# Getting operation not permitted when trying to open projects or use integrated terminal in emacs-doom

Tags: osx

While using MacOS Catalina (which is suspect is the problem) I recently decided to try emacs, as a recommendation from a friend. I finally get it working and generally figure it out and now when trying to open a project or even trying to ls my Downloads or Documents folder I get an operation not permitted error. I have checked my user (whoami) which the user has permission to run the commands, and I have granted full disk access to all emacs applications I could find, yet to no avail.

UPDATE:
Got it working by running `csrutil disable` in recovery mode (yes I understand what the effects of this are), however I still have this error:
[image] 
Any idea how to resolve this? The only way I can add files to the current project is by using `:edit FILENAME` however I can edit the files just fine, and can run `find .` in any folder using the integrated terminal.

Comment: AFAICT this is not an Emacs problem as much as a macos problem.

Comment: It must have something to do with emacs, as I have granted the emacs app full disk access, and made sure that the folders are readable by any user

Comment: IIUC Catalina added more constraints and your description makes it sound like Emacs is bumping against some of them.  I don't think there's anything you can do within your `.emacs` to fix that: it has to be fixed from outside (which is what I mean by "it's a macos problem", even if it only affects Emacs).

Comment: I do not have such problems - I have Emacs application added to Privacy tab - Accessibility in Settings->Security & Privacy. Then if you access a folder like Documents, it will show up as checked in Privacy tab -> File and Folders, after you gives it the access right.

Comment: @Ian your hint doesn't work

Comment: I have tried it following the steps from here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371888/restore-access-to-file-system-for-emacs-on-macos-catalina

It works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try running emacs from a terminal:

```
$ emacs -nw
```

If it works this way, it means the permissions restrictions is applied only to Emacs.app and can be solved giving permissions to `ruby`, as explained [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371888/restore-access-to-file-system-for-emacs-on-macos-catalina/371945#371945).

It sounds weird, but it works like a charm. It is because the desktop app is launched using `ruby`.